# MoqAutoMocker and primitive constructor parameters

Tags: .net, unit-testing, structuremap, automocking

I am an avid user of the StructureMap MoqAutoMocker, sometimes, however, we run into an "old friend" of ours. Assume a class "Validator"

```
public class Validator
{
   private string _connectionString;
   private IEventMachine _eventMachine;

   public Validator(string connectionString, IEventMachine eventMachine)
   {
      _connectionString = connectionString;
      _eventMachine = eventMachine;
   }
}
```

The class above doesn't really matter, in fact, it will probably raise a few eyebrows, I'm just making it for this post, as I could not think of a better example off the tip of my nose. The point is that it contains a mix of primitive datatypes ( *connectionString*) and interfaces (*eventMachine*) - during unit testing, I typically set my expectations, such as:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Validate_WhenCalled_PublishesEnterEvent()
{
    // Arrange
    var Instance = new MoqAutoMocker<Validator>();
    var eventMachineMock = Mock.Get(AutoMock.Get<IEventMachine>());

    // Act
    Instance.Validate();

    // Assert
    eventMachineMock.Verify(m => m.Publish( It.IsAny<string>(), Times.Once());        
}
```

So, the question is: 
The above will not work, because **MoqAutoMocker** fails to accept the connectionString argument, as it cannot find an interface for it (or any other primitive for that matter). My question is simply: Is there a way to tell MoqAutoMocker what this value should be?

In advance, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I dont beleive there is a way - it is a limitation of the AutoMocker.

We tend to avoid primitive constructor params in favor of settings objects (see [How we handle application configuration](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/joshuaflanagan/archive/2009/07/12/how-we-handle-application-configuration.aspx))